# Shouldn't Ctrl + A in a code-block select the block's code instead of the entire page?

Tags: feature-request, code

When you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> on a Stack Overflow page, regardless of content, the default browser behavior is used -- which is to highlight everything on the page.

Other sites (like Gmail, etc.) have a neat JavaScript feature that converts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to a local selection for useful reasons.

I would suggest the excellent developers at Stack Exchange make such a feature. (i.e. trigger a JavaScript function when a user clicks in a code block that prepares <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the local code).

I can see reasons to avoid changing the default behavior -- in such a case, maybe it's time for a [copy] button next to all code blocks :-)

Alas, if not, I will continue my laborious click-and-drag (and scroll if needed) method.

EDIT:

This is apparently a feature-request that has been [ignored for a long time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251883/select-all-copy-all-button-for-code).

Comment: Related: *[Easy way top copy text from the code block?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344880)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen, the post's deleted. This should be *fixed*, as it should *just not select the entire page, as it's used in a code block*.