# How do I contact Stack Overflow with a suggestion? My question already exists: Should there a copy-to-clipboard button/icon next to all code snippets?

Tags: feature-request

How do I contact Stack Overflow with a suggestion? I was going to ask this question in Meta, but I see it already exists: [Select All / Copy All Button for Code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251883/select-all-copy-all-button-for-code)

1. Someone visits Stack Overflow.
2. They see an answer.
3. The answer has code.
4. They need the code in their IDE.

Currently this take about 3-4 actions from the user:

- They select all text (either click-and-drag cursor or double-click: two actions).
- They copy to the clipboard (either Ctrl + C or right-click > Copy: two more actions).

If there was a copy-to-clipboard button next to all code snippets (```) then users would need to take only one action (click the button) to get the code onto the clipboard, saving everyone massive time overall.

Comment: I think that they already know full well about this suggestion, and their actions or non-actions probably reveal its importance to them.

Comment: This is really just a duplicate of the question you linked. You should upvote that question, and if you really want the button yourself, use the userscript linked in the answers there or write one yourself

Comment: You can also give [this question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow) an upvote too.

Comment: @Joundill Thanks! If I write one myself, then I have to advertise for others to benefit from my labor. If StackOverflow writes it, all users benefit immediately. Is it not less work overall for all humans for the website to change than for users to write extensions and share those extensions and maintain those extensions as the website changes?

Comment: If you write one yourself, definitely link to it in an answer to those two questions. Others will appreciate the effort you've put in

Comment: Workaround: Use a macro keyboard (or some software solution, like [AutoIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) - though that usually doesn't work across Windows and Linux (unlike a macro keyboard)). The Stack Overflow (physical) [3-key keyboard](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) is fully programmable through [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/) and is suitable for this. So is an [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers) (or the equivalent, including most boards based on  the [ATmega32U4](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega32U4)).

Answer (score -5):

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71741/1120076) says copy-to-clipboard "simply will not be implemented due to security concerns".

There is [a Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-copy-button/dkejincbnheemdddmbiggcnlidffpedf) and [a Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stack-copy-button/) in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/MrMino/StackCtrlC) (from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255452/569302)).